# Method to append data to list affects multiple objects

Tags: python

I am writing a simple dynamics model that includes position, velocity, ect for multiple objects.

```
    class airplane
       history=[]
       def record(self,time,timestep=.1):
           self.history.append([time*timestep,self.position[0],self.position[1],self.position[2]])
       def output(self):
           self.data=pandas.DataFrame(self.history,columns=['time','x','y','z'])
for i in range(10):
    airplane1.record(i)
    airplane2.record(i)
airplane1.output()
airplane2.output()
```

Each data frame has 20 rows containing the alternating positions of each airplane.  How do I make record only append data to the history list of the called object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `history` an *instance* attribute, rather than a *class* attribute that is shared by all instances of the class, by creating it in an `__init__` method. I have corrected your code: You need to create instances `airplane1` and `airplane2` before you can use them and nowhere do you create instance attribute list `position`, so I have commented out the reference to that and substituted constants for now (you need to correct this). I also added a `print` statement to demonstrate the output. Also, it is usual to name classes with capital letters.

```
import pandas

class airplane:
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = []
    def record(self,time,timestep=.1):
        #self.history.append([time*timestep,self.position[0],self.position[1],self.position[2]])
        self.history.append([time*timestep, 0, 1, 2])
    def output(self):
        self.data=pandas.DataFrame(self.history,columns=['time','x','y','z'])
        print(self.data)

airplane1 = airplane()
airplane2 = airplane()
for i in range(10):
    airplane1.record(i)
    airplane2.record(i)

airplane1.output()
airplane2.output()
```

Prints:

```
   time  x  y  z
0   0.0  0  1  2
1   0.1  0  1  2
2   0.2  0  1  2
3   0.3  0  1  2
4   0.4  0  1  2
5   0.5  0  1  2
6   0.6  0  1  2
7   0.7  0  1  2
8   0.8  0  1  2
9   0.9  0  1  2
   time  x  y  z
0   0.0  0  1  2
1   0.1  0  1  2
2   0.2  0  1  2
3   0.3  0  1  2
4   0.4  0  1  2
5   0.5  0  1  2
6   0.6  0  1  2
7   0.7  0  1  2
8   0.8  0  1  2
9   0.9  0  1  2
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question.  The other instances, attributes, and calls are all in there.  I had tried to only include the relevant lines in the question.

Comment: Well, you didn't.